# Gradle idea NPE modifying ipr file

Tags: intellij-idea, nullpointerexception, gradle

I have the following in my build.gradle for one of my sub-submodules:

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'idea'

dependencies {
  compile project(':x')
  compile project(':y')
  compile project(':z')
}

idea {
  module.iml.withXml {
    // do some stuff
  }
  project.ipr.withXml {
    // do some more stuff
  }
}
```

However when I run `gradle build` I get the following error:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':a:b'
  ...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'ipr' on null object
  ...
```

at the line where I call `project.ipr`. Oddly enough, if I remove the `apply plugin: 'idea'` line, the error disappears and when I run `gradle idea` the task specified in the closures above gets executed (I think because the plugin is applied to the parent project).

Why is this error happening? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rookie mistake: the `project` property is only available if the module is the root one. Makes sense. I was able to modify the ipr file from a submodule using:

```
rootProject.idea.project.ipr.withXml { /* modify ipr */ }
```